# Jar Signing Strategy in Maven Projects

Tags: maven, maven-2, continuous-integration, signing, jarsigner

We have several maven projects, which are built on the build server. In some cases we want to sign our deliverables. We use [Maven Jarsigner Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jarsigner-plugin/) to do that.

We face the following questions:

- Where should we store the passwords for signing?
- What is a good strategy for signing maven projects?

We don't want to put our keystore somewhere on our servers and hardcode a path to it. So we just wrapped this keystore in a jar and uploaded it as an artifact to our inner maven repository. When we want to sign a maven project, we download the keystore artifact using the [Maven Dependency Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) and attach signing goal to maven build lifecycle. [Here](http://maksim.sorokin.dk/it/2010/08/19/signing-jars-on-a-build-server/) is more detailed information.

In order to hide the passwords for the keystore, we put them into our corporate `pom.xml` file. We also think about storing passwords in `settings.xml` on the build server.

When a project is built and signed on a developer machine, we sign it with self-signed certificate. But when project is built and signed on a build server, we sign it with our "official" certificate.

Is it a good strategy?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I use 2 keystores:

- a development keystore which is stored in the SCM. The CI server can thus sign the snapshots.
- a production keystore with a real production certificate issued by a trusted certification authority.

The development keystore password is in the `pom.xml`. Here is a snippet of my `pom.xml`:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <storetype>${keystore.type}</storetype>
      <keystore>${keystore.path}</keystore>
      <alias>${keystore.alias}</alias>
      <storepass>${keystore.store.password}</storepass>
      <keypass>${keystore.key.password}</keypass>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <!-- 
      ... rest of the pom.xml ...
  -->
  <properties>
    <keystore.path>cert/temp.keystore</keystore.path>
    <keystore.type>JKS</keystore.type>
    <keystore.alias>dev</keystore.alias>
    <keystore.password>dev_password</keystore.password>
    <keystore.store.password>${keystore.password}</keystore.store.password>
    <keystore.key.password>${keystore.password}</keystore.key.password>
  </properties>
```

In `~/.m2/settings.xml` I defined a `codesgining` profile:

```
<settings>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>codesigning</id>
      <properties>
        <keystore.path>/opt/prod/prod.keystore</keystore.path> 
        <keystore.alias>prod</keystore.alias>
        <keystore.type>JKS</keystore.type>
        <keystore.store.password>${keystore.password}</keystore.store.password>
        <keystore.key.password>${keystore.password}</keystore.key.password>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</settings>
```

when I want to sign the real certificate I invoke maven with the `-Pcodesigning -Dkeystore.password=strongPassword` parameters. I also configured the [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/) to use the `codesigning` profile.

Actually it is possible to store the password in `settings.xml` as long as the file is readable by nobody but you.

Comment: We went the same way. Except that production keystore passwords are stored in profile settings.xml. And that profile is invoked by the build server automatically.

Comment: Also note, your alias can't contain a single-quote character due to this bug: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MJARSIGNER-11

Comment: As of version 1.3, the jar signer plugin supports maven encryption. This makes it relatively safe to store the password in settings.xml. Check out http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html for the details.

Comment: The closing settings tag is missing the a forward slash.